# Issue with Ruby running install file

Tags: ruby, centos

I have Ruby v1.8.7 on my host with Centos, but I need to have a version 2.xx to install a particular application. I installed RVM and set it to default to Ruby 2.2.4.

```
[root@test.01]# rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]

=> - current
=* - current && default
* - default
```

When I run install file it is returning the error:

```
[root@test-01]# sudo ./install auto
./install:29:in `require': no such file to load -- logger (LoadError)
from ./install:29
```

Comment: Try `gem install logger`

Comment: Tried it @SergioTulentsev..but still seeing the same issue 
[root@test01]# gem install logger
Fetching: logger-1.2.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed logger-1.2.8
Parsing documentation for logger-1.2.8
Installing ri documentation for logger-1.2.8
Done installing documentation for logger after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
[root@test01]# sudo ./install 
./install:29:in `require': no such file to load -- logger (LoadError)
 from ./install:29

Comment: why the `sudo`?

Comment: What happens when you run `ruby -version` in the directory? Is it correct? Also, the `sudo` should not be necessary

Comment: It ran successfully when i just executed ./install but throwing error as required ruby version more than 1.9.XX ..using RVM i defaulted 2.2.4 but it is taking 1.8.7 as centos has 1.8.7 installed when the instance was triggered ..